# Rails not rendering a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

I can't get my page to render a partial. When I pull run it on the server it does not render the partial at all, but just skips it. No error messages.

```
# edit.html.erb    
<%= link_to("<< Back to List", {:action => 'list'}, :class => 'back=link')%>

<div class="subject edit">
    <h2>Edit Subject</h2>
    
    <%= form_for(:subject, :url => {:action => 'update', :id=>@subject.id}) do |f| %>
    
        <% render :partial => 'form', :locals => {:f => f} %>
    
        <div class="form-buttons">
            <%= submit_tag("Update Subject")%>
        </div>
    
    <% end %>
</div>
```

and this is _form.html.erb

```
<table summary="Subject form fields">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:name) %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Position</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:position) %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Visible</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:visible) %></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need the `=` sign:

```
<%= render :partial => 'form', :locals => {:f => f} %>
```

(you had `<% render ....`)

Comment: I cannot believe I did this. Again! But once here, to note that in Rails 4+ you can omit partial and locals: `= render 'form', f: f`. Much shorter.

Comment: this is a common mistake noobs like me doo thanks for pointing it out